# Beautifulsoup scaping Google reviews (google places)

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to scrape User reviews from Google places reviews (the API only returns 5 most helpful reviews). I am attempting to use Beautifulsoup to  retrieve 4 pieces of information
1) Name of the reviewer
2) When the review was written
3) Rating (out of 5) 
4) Body of review

Inspecting each element I can find the location of the information

1) Name of reviewer:

```html
<a class="_e8k" style="color:black;text-decoration:none" href="https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/103603482673238284204/reviews">Steve Fox</a>
```

2) When the review was written

```html
<span style="color:#999;font-size:13px">3 months ago</span>
```

3) Rating (visible in code, but doesn't show when "run code snippet"

```html
<span class="_pxg _Jxg" aria-label="Rated 1.0 out of 5,"><span style="width:14px"></span></span>
```

4) Body of the review

```html
<span jsl="$t t-uvHqeLvCkgA;$x 0;" class="r-i8GVQS_tBTbg">Don't go near this company.  Must be the world's worst ISP.  Threatened to set debt collection services on me when I refused to pay for a service that they had cut off through  competence.  They even spitefully  managed to apply block on our internet connection after we moved to a new Isp.  I hate this company.</span>
```

I am struggling with how to refer to the position of information within the HTML. I see the last 3 pieces of information are in spans so I attempted the following- but none of relevant information was returned

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.co.nz/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=orcon&lrd=0x6d0d3833fefacf95:0x59fef608692d4541,1,').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')
attempt1 = soup.find_all('span class')
for span in attempt1:
    print(span)
```

I assume I am not correctly/accurately referencing the 4 pieces of information within the HTML. Can some point out what is wrong? Regards Steve

Comment: are you sure the url in you code is right, i open it and it's a google search page, not contain the info you want

Comment: or you can just post the source code of the page

Comment: I wouldn't waste too much time on it, as Google's going to start throwing up captchas if you do this for long.

Comment: URL now corrrected

Answer (score 1):

To scrape the reviews of a place you'll need the place id. It looks like this `0x89c259a61c75684f:0x79d31adb123348d2`.

And then you need to make the request with the fallowing url that contains the `place_id`:

https://www.google.com/async/reviewDialog?hl=en&async=feature_id:0x89c259a61c75684f:0x79d31adb123348d2,sort_by:,next_page_token:,associated_topic:,_fmt:pc

Alternatively you could use a third party solution like SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial. We handle proxies, solve captchas, and parse all the rich structured data for you.

Example python code (available in other libraries also):

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "engine": "google_maps_reviews",
  "place_id": "0x89c259a61c75684f:0x79d31adb123348d2",
  "hl": "en",
  "api_key": "secret_api_key"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()
```

Example JSON output:

```json
"reviews": [
  {
    "user": {
      "name": "HerbertTomlinson O",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/100851257830988379503?hl=en-US&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiIlNzLtJrxAhVFWs0KHfclCwAQvvQBegQIARAy",
      "thumbnail": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AATXAJyjD5T8NEJSdOUAveA8IuMDTLXE9edBHDpFTvZ8=s40-c-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-br100",
      "reviews": 2
    },
    "rating": 4,
    "date": "2 months ago",
    "snippet": "Finally, I found the best coffee shop today. Their choice of music is usually blasting from the past which was really relaxing and made me stay longer. There are tables for lovers and also for group of friends. The coffees and foods here are very affordable and well worth the money. You can't go wrong with this coffee shop. This is very worth to visit."
  },
  {
    "user": {
      "name": "Izaac Collier",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/116734781291082397423?hl=en-US&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiIlNzLtJrxAhVFWs0KHfclCwAQvvQBegQIARA-",
      "thumbnail": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GgfhltPhiWrkTwe6swLUQRCWf_asuTfHPRnJCLc=s40-c-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-br100",
      "reviews": 2
    },
    "rating": 5,
    "date": "a month ago",
    "snippet": "I am not into coffee but one of my friends invited me here. As I looked the menu, I was convinced, so I ordered one for me. The food was tasty and the staff were very friendly and accommodating. The ambience was very cosy and comfortable. The coffee was great and super tasty. I will recommend this and will visit again!"
  },
  ...
```

Check out the [documentation](https://serpapi.com/google-maps-reviews-api) for more details.

*Disclaimer: I work at SerpApi.*